# How to compile multiple plots into a single plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently trying to combine multiple plots into a single plot (with sub-plots). Please check out the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = list(range(1,10))
b = list(map(lambda x: x**2, a))
c = list(map(lambda x: x**3, a))
d = list(map(lambda x: x+200, a))

plots = []

plt.plot(a, b)
plots.append(plt.gcf())
plt.close()

plt.plot(a, c)
plots.append(plt.gcf())
plt.close()

plt.plot(b, c)
plots.append(plt.gcf())
plt.close()

plt.plot(a, d)
plots.append(plt.gcf())
plt.close()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(plots))
for i,plot_obj in enumerate(plots, start=1):
    print(f"{i=}, {plot_obj=}")
    ax[i].set_figure(plot_obj)
    plot_obj.show()


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

The constraints I have are -

1. The plots will be created earlier - I'm storing the `figure` objects in a list.
2. These plots need to be accessed later on in the code and a single figure needs to be created with each of the plot as a sub-plot.

On running the above code, I'm encountering the error - `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure` while trying to set the figure of each sub-plot. The thought process is to set each sub-plots's figure with the saved `figure` object. Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Thanks!

Comment: why not using subplots, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subplot-py)

Comment: @ted930511 It doesn't help. The link tells you how to plot multiple sub-plots, what I'm looking for is more specific than that. The plots are generated before, and later a single figure needs to be created by compiling all the plots.

Comment: I want this functionality because single figure is expensive to plot ?

Comment: The issue is that calling `plt.figure()` without arguments creates a **new** figure, so what your code appends to the `plots` list are those new figures and not the plots that you want.

Comment: @Arne Yes, you're correct. I've updated the code now. I can save the figures in files while traversing through the plots, but I'm not able to build the final plot with the sub-plots as each saved plot.

Answer (score 2):

If you save the individual plots to files, you can later use `imshow()` and `imread()` from the `matplotlib.image` library to piece them together into one plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

a = list(range(1,10))
b = list(map(lambda x: x**2, a))
c = list(map(lambda x: x**3, a))
d = list(map(lambda x: x+200, a))

def save_plot(x, y, name):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.figure.savefig(name)
    plt.close()
        
save_plot(a, b, 'plot1')
save_plot(a, c, 'plot2')
save_plot(b, c, 'plot3')
save_plot(a, d, 'plot4')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    ax.set_axis_off()
    filename = 'plot' + str(i+1) + '.png'
    ax.imshow(mpimg.imread(filename))
plt.show()
```

You may want to look into the `imshow()` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html) to reduce the whitespace around each subplot.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it's a good workaround. Thanks @Arne !

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cleanest way to write it, but I guess it does what you want:

```
a = list(range(1,10))
b = list(map(lambda x: x**2, a))
c = list(map(lambda x: x**3, a))
d = list(map(lambda x: x+200, a))

plots = []

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, b)
plots.append(fig)
plt.close()

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, c)
plots.append(fig)
plt.close()

fig=plt.figure()
ax3= plt.plot(b, c)
plots.append(fig)
plt.close()

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, d)
plots.append(fig)
plt.close()

fig,axs =plt.subplots(2,2)
axs[0,0].plot(a,b)
axs[0,1].plot(a,c)
axs[1,0].plot(b,c)
axs[1,1].plot(a,d)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not what I'm looking for. Your code saves the `figure` objects in `plots` list, but doesn't make use of them during the final figure (with subplot) creation. Moreover, each sub-plot is created by plotting the data again. Basically, the last few LOCs does the whole work. I need the plot objects to be saved first and then later on use them in sub-plots. The thing is, my project won't have access to the data (a,b,c,d) when building the final figure, only the `figure` objects will be there.